# Open external links of inappbrowser with _system - cordova

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I made a simple cordova app. Installed inappbrowser plugin & ondeviceready it will initialize inappbrowser & will open specific URL/website.

Now that website is having downloads links like pdf, doc etc.. I know that will not open within inappbrowser, correct me if I am wrong. But what is the solution?

Straight and short question is all links are working fine but what if any link with download link like pdf? I want them to open somehow.. it should pop up with opener or anything else.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is Solved by following code! But once pdf link clicked, loadstart stop calling when I back to my App.

```
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,"_blank", 'location=no');

    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
        var url = e.url;
        var extension = url.split('.').pop();
   if (extension == 'pdf' || extension == 'jpg' || extension == 'doc' || extension == 'docx' || extension == 'xls' || extension == 'xlsx') {
        {
           var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", 'location=no');
        }
     });
```

Only works with pdf